# Error - Instance member cannot be used on type custom class

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to get today's date

```
import Foundation

class Date {
  var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  var day = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: NSDate())
}
```

But I keep getting error

```
Instance member 'calendar' cannot be used on type 'Date'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access calendar property at instantiation time:

Try like this:

```
class Date {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var day: Int {
       return  calendar.component(.Day, fromDate: NSDate())
    }
}


print(Date().day)   // 17
```